# Controller method called synchronously

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Take the [default starter app for java](https://github.com/playframework/play-java-starter-example) and add the following to `HomeController`'s `index` method:

```
System.out.println("Before");
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("After");
```

Then run a few tabs in a browser calling `http://localhost:9000`.

The expected behavior is that `Before` is printed as soon as the request is issued from the browser tab.
While the actual result is that consequent requests start executing only *after* the previous one has finished. Note that this is only observed when calling the same method in a controller: two different methods successfully run simultaneously.

Maybe I'm getting something wrong, but I tried nearly all possible configurations in `application.conf` and it looked like the thread pools had enough threads, still I couldn't accomplish the simultaneous execution of the method in different threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by your browser refusing to issue simultaneous requests to the same resource, and nothing to do with Play. When I run the same test on my machine, I see Chrome making an upper limit of two requests to the index page regardless of how many tabs I have open, while when I run curl from multiple different console windows, I see no such limit.

Your browser is really not the right tool to be using to run a test like this.

Comment: Wow that's unexpected. Thanks.